Can't change accessibility to field in unit test . getDeclaredField can't find my field
I have the problem that my getDeclaredField can't find my field, and I can't find why. Any ideas?
public interface MapInterface<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {

    public void setValue(K key, V value);

    public V getValue(K key);

}

This is the class that implements that interface:
public class RbtMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements MapInterface<K, V> {

    private final RedBlackTree<K, V> tree;

    public <K, V> RbtMap() {
        tree = new RedBlackTree<>();
    }

In my unit test, I try get access to tree
Field treeField = RbtMap.class.getDeclaredField("tree");

but I have that:

Unhandled exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException

I don't know what I should do.

"Unhandled exception" is compilation error. In your case it suggests that you need try-catch section handling java.lang.NoSuchFieldException in which you decide what you want to do when searched field is not found. OR you can let your methods propagate this error farther to its caller by adding throws java.lang.NoSuchFieldException in its declaration. Only then your code can be compiled and then you can run it.

^^ But what you should do is avoid engaging reflection to test your classes.  It's poor form to couple unit tests to the implementation details of your classes, as you do by reflecting their internals.

add throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException to method signature
like below
@Test
public void test() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
        Field treeField = RbtMap.class.getDeclaredField("tree");
        System.out.println(treeField.getName());
}


Or, because it is a test anyway, and specificity is not really needed, just add throws Exception.
